# Output Parquet file is very big in size after repartitioning with column in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, google-cloud-dataproc

The dataframe which I am trying to repartition based on column is generating a single file of more than 500MB size.

```
df.repartition(col("column_name")).write.parquet("gs://path_of_bucket")
```

Is their a way to limit the size of output parquet file to 128MB? I don't want to use number of partitions as output can vary hourly. I am using dataproc cluster and output is going into GCS bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-sql-configuration) to split dataframe being written into files of `X` rows each.

> **Property Name** spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile
>  **Default** 0
> **Meaning**   Maximum number of records to write out to a single file. If
> this value is zero or negative, there is no limit.
>  **Since Version**  2.2.0

If your rows are more or less uniform in length, you can estimate the number X that would give your desired size (128MB).