# Does pyspark loaded pipeline model store metadata after transforming unseen data?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark logistic regression model which is saved like:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel
stages = feature_stage_list \
            + label_stage_list \
            + assembler_stage_list \
            + classifier_stage_list \
            + label_converter_stage_list
pipeline = Pipeline(stages = stages)
pipeline_model = pipeline.fit(input_df)
pipeline_model.save(output_path)
```

that saved model is then loaded and used to transform some unseen data:

```
pipeline_model = PipelineModel.load(input_path)
predictions_df = pipeline_model.transform(unseen_df).repartition(100)
predictions_df.write.parquet(new_output_path)
```

as for input, I have 200 x 140KB files so not too large at all. Now, the above transform and repartition statement generates output files of size ~140MB each and when I change the number of partitions to 200, I'd still get the same file sizes as before. I'm suspecting that's because how the whole pipeline load model works and probably the metadata of the model is stored in every one of those output files? I've looked here and there for an explanation about this but can't find anything useful so any help with this would be great.

Comment: If you just want to get smaller output files, perhaps you can use `spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile` instead of repartitioning the whole dataframe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76803950/output-parquet-file-is-very-big-in-size-after-repartitioning-with-column-in-spar